# Maintaining modularity while keeping (secret) configuration separate from application code

Tags: security, environment, information

This is more a curiosity/query-for-information than anything; apologies if it's thus a little malformed:

This is relevant to a useful API-querying library that can be shared across multiple teams within the company.

Consider the scenario wherein all configuration is propagated via environment variables. Anything that needs something like an environment-specific URL just pings (in the case of Python) `os.envion.get("ENVIRONMENT_SPECIFIC_URL")`. But, this presents a problem for security-sensitive environment variables like API keys. Even if the means of populating the environment is itself secure (e.g., decrypting an encrypted secrets file), the decrypted secret is sitting in a persistent environment and can be accessed by anything that manages to read said environment. This probably isn't a problem in most cases, but it isn't ideal.

Honestly, I think environment variables are almost ideal; you leave their population to whatever you want, while the configured code can be used anywhere.

- Is there a means of using environment variables... *securely*?
- Are there other ways to maintain this separation of configuration and application code?

I've considered a few things, some funnier than others:

- Environment variables that are populated on build, but discarded afterwards. *This too tightly couples configured code by requiring it to only check the environment at build-time.*
- Using a secrets manager. *This also couples configured code. I don't want to have to e.g. use the google secrets module whenever a request is made*
- A configuration class. *" "*
- Here's the funny one I really want to ask about: Encrypted environment variables that are decrypted when accessed and encrypted again. I don't even know how this would work. Would it be something running in the background constantly? *No, hopefully not*. Something that neatly injects itself into whatever environment variables are accessed *... maybe? Maybe something like overriding an attribute?*

Comment: It is unclear what kind of execution environment you have in mind (from the POV of security).  This makes it even more unclear what your threat model is.

Comment: @DocBrown Would you mind explaining a bit? If it's not obvious, I don't think much about security outside of employing what are said to be common-best-practices. So, from the point of view of security, "threat model" is—how do I expect anyone to get into a position where they can see the environment of my deployment?

Comment: Assume that the library {reads, writes, incurs charges} against three commercial APIs using env vars KEY_A, KEY_B, KEY_C. We have Alice developing the library, her colleague Bob is part of the sales forecasting development team, her colleague Carol is on the DevOps team, her colleague Dave is an end user, interacting via browser with sales forecast reports. Sometimes we find config and code defects. That's the deployment environment. Now tell us, what is the threat model? What kind of Bad Things are we concerned might happen? How big of an effect? How to mitigate?

Comment: How the users of the library chose to configure it, is usually outside the control of the library itself. Only a few things you can ensure internally, like never log, transmit or store configuration in an unsecure way. From the question, it is unclear what kind of control you want to have over the way the environment variables are configured.

Comment: Encrypting secrets within an environment is typically just a "placebo", being that anyone who has access to that environment will almost certainly have some means of decrypting any information they find on it.  Instead consider what you might be able to achieve by securing the whole environment - e.g. MFA access to the device, disk/drive encryption, physical security, restricted accounts, etc.    In general, if a system is not secure enough for you to be able to confidently leave secrets as plain-text then you likely have a much wider problem which won't be fixed by encrypting those secrets.